Change output language of internal commands like "lpstat"?
I've written some AppleScripts that run shell commands like lpstat -a and lpstat -l -p and parse the output with grep and awk. The scripts work correctly in English-language system, but the output is different in non-English systems.
The only workaround I've found is impractical: I have four strings that are different in English systems and non-English systems, so I've created variables that the script work in English and French. But it's impossible to do this for every language. So is there a way to force the output of lpstat to be in English, no matter what the system language is?


Looking through the Apple-modified version of cups/language.c (specifically, 10.6.8’s language.c), I found that you should be able to override the language by setting LANG to your preferred language as long as you also set SOFTWARE (any value, even the empty string).

lpstat and localization under Mac OS X (unix.stackexchange.com)
So:
SOFTWARE= LANG=C lpstat -a


This is perfect! Thank you!

One more question: What does LANG=C mean? Does it refer to the C programming language or is some way to refer to a human language? I suppose that it refers to the programming language, but I've never seen that kind of entry for LANG before.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614923/how-is-the-locale-of-a-c-program-set-to-the-c-locale

I should have found that myself. Thank you!

To make this answer more complete, I think it would be great if you could include how to set the language to a few other major languages (maybe French and Spanish for example). I assume you have to set LANG=C to something else, but it's not obvious to me what letter you'd use. This is probably in the link in your earlier comment, but I couldn't figure it out in a quick skim!

Use the ISO 639/3166 locale name for the language you want in place of "C"; for example LANG=fr_FR for European French. Only supported locales will work, obviously.
